# I can't target all mobs expect player in a 5 block radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried using this command to give every entity in a 5 block radius

```
[/effect @e[r=5, type=!player] minecraft:levitation 10 1 true].
```

I expect player levitation, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you really have the square brackets around the command? If yes, delete the. And the dot at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a space in there that you shouldn't have here is the fixed command

```
/effect @e[r=5,type=!player] minecraft:levitation 10 1 true
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the players to also receive levitation, remove the "type=!player" from your selector. That argument excludes player entities from being targeted.

> /effect @e[r=5] minecraft:levitation 10 1 true

Comment: I wanted to target every mob but players but thanks anyway

Comment: The wording of your question confused me. My apologies. By "I expect player levitation" I thought you meant "I expected the player to receive levitation"